# Revealing module pattern template

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have the following that works fine for one page but I want to make it available for 2 more pages:

```
 var dynamicPropertyOverviewController = (function(){

    var currentPage = $('#dynamicPropertyOverview');

    function init(){
        if(checkMobileAndTabletVisibility.isTabletView()){
            if(dynamicPropertyController.isDynamicPropertyOverviewWithAvailability(currentPage)){
                dynamicPropertyController.addSearchModalMobileTrigger();
                if(dynamicPropertyController.isSearchBarNotHidden()){
                    dynamicPropertyController.hideSearchBarDisplayPill(currentPage);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            dynamicPropertyController.addSearchBarDesktopTrigger();
        }
    }

    return{
        init: init
    }

})();
```

"currentPage" var will determine where this init is going to be applied.

This is just to have a better idea of where all these functions come from:

```
    var dynamicPropertyController = (function() {

        var searchBarModalTrigger = 'js-open-mobile-search';

        function isDynamicPropertyOverviewWithAvailability(page){
            return page.length && !$('.property-not-available').length;
        }

        function hideSearchBarDisplayPill(page){
            page.addClass('hide-search-form');
        $('.check-prices').addClass('display-pill');    
    }

    function addSearchModalMobileTrigger(){
        $('.edit-search-link').removeClass('display-searchBar').addClass(searchBarModalTrigger);
    }
```

How can I make

```
    function addSearchBarDesktopTrigger(){
        $('.edit-search-link').removeClass(searchBarModalTrigger).addClass('display-searchBar');
    }

    function isSearchBarNotHidden(){
        return !$('.hide-search-form').length;
    }

    return {
        isDynamicPropertyOverviewWithAvailability: isDynamicPropertyOverviewWithAvailability,
        hideSearchBarDisplayPill: hideSearchBarDisplayPill,
        addSearchModalMobileTrigger: addSearchModalMobileTrigger,
        addSearchBarDesktopTrigger: addSearchBarDesktopTrigger,
        isSearchBarNotHidden: isSearchBarNotHidden
    }

})();
```

How can I make "dynamicPropertyOverviewController" so that I can just pass one variable and use it across 3 different pages?

Comment: Don't make it a module but a factory?

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern allows you to use expose a var accross diferent modules:

```
window.App = {};
window.App.sharedVariable = "Same value";
(function (App) {
    console.log("I can read App.sharedVariable", App.sharedVariable);

}(window.App));

(function (App) {
    console.log("I can read App.sharedVariable too!", App.sharedVariable);
}(window.App));

(function (App) {
    App.sharedVariable = "Changed the value!"
}(window.App));

(function (App) {
  console.log("he did changed App.sharedVariable", App.sharedVariable);
   console.log("you can even have custom event listeners and trigger it when the variable is changed and stuff, neat hun ?");
}(window.App));
```

I've keep it very basic and simple so that you can apply this knowledge everywhere! This can be useful and you don't need to struggle much to understand it and fits your current problem really well!

You can find a working example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXPOZg?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

I have found something that could work for me:

```
function CarPartFactory() {}
CarPartFactory.prototype.createPart = function createCarPart( options ) {
  console.log(options + ' options');
}

var seat = new CarPartFactory();

// outputs a CarSeat object with material "leather", color "blue", isReclinable "false"
seat.createPart('page');
```

Like this I can pass any page that I like